# Logstash file input plugin returning duplicate events

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

So i am using file plugin in logstash to input logs from multiple files.

```
Path => “/path/to/a*.txt”
```

I have two files: a1.txt and a2.txt.
Now i start logstash, both files’ data gets sent to stdout. But when i make a new entry in any of the file, it sends that new line, but also sends the second last line again.
I’ve set the start_position to “beginning”.
Any idea what is going on?

Comment: could you post your logstash config please?

Comment: I resolved it actually. So the thing is if you open the file and  modify it, it’s inode number changes! Then this new inode number also get’s registered as an entry in sincedb file. Hence the duplicates.

Comment: I think you should write your comment as an answer and accept it since you solved it. Completely normal. The question will be officialy answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it actually. So the thing is if you open the file and modify it, it’s inode number changes! Then this new inode number also get’s registered as an entry in sincedb file. Hence the duplicates.